# God Only Knows The Answer

Tags: knowledge, rebus, music

Can you identfy the song lyric hinted at here?  Read from left to right, from the top.

[image]

Comment: This is kinda scary... For the last two weeks or so, I had the exact same song in my head with the exact same top row in mind.

Comment: @QBrute Perhaps the best song ever written about erotic woodcarving and frozen natto.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is:

> "Wouldn't it be nice" by the Beach Boys.

With the translation:

> WOODEN TEAT | BEAN ICE | SIF WEEK | HOOD | WEIGH CUP
>  Wouldn't it be nice if we could wake up
>
>  Fixed now to be "Sif Week", since I just noticed they are all characters called Sif.  Duh.

Oh, and slight extra:

> The Beach Boys also sang "God Only Knows" which is the puzzle title!

And an edit note:

> I realise that one word could be replaced by a "better" homophone, but it was purposefully edited to this to be as polite as possible... ^^;

Comment: One last improvement--it's not just a teat, it's the entire...

Comment: And it wasn't my first version with fewer letters? :P  I "cleaned it up" to this word, which is at least anatomically correct... if not quite as homophonic. ^^;

Comment: That's fair.  Perhaps it's one of the Seven Dirty Words You Can't Say On StackExchange!

Comment: Personally, I am not offended... But I have no idea what the rules are and this seemed like a good way to get out of the problem ;p